# Django Web App - Axios 502 Error - Debugging

Tags: django, axios

I'm not that familiar with Django and Axios, but I'm currently getting a 502 Error. Here's the console error that appears:
M {message: 'Request failed with status code 502', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_RESPONSE', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}

Does anybody know what this means or where I should start to debug this? Is this a front end error or a back end error?

I tried editing both my API and front end code back to a version that worked before but it's still not working for some reason. I also logged into my server console log but it doesn't seem to be logging any error related to this api call.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the axios request that you're doing?

Comment: I'm trying to request data from an api so I can use to build a graph of health data. I pass through the patient id. For context, here's part of the axios call code: 
  axios.post('/api/diagnostics/dashboard/', {
        patient_ids: [{{ID}}],
      }).then(({data}) => {

        cached_data["values"] = data;
        visSpec["data"] = cached_data;

        // apply filters needed and draw the vis!
        filter_changed();
      }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
      });